# iOS 9 Local notifications not working on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I know there are a few similar topics already posted, but I have followed them and still had the same problem.

My AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    application.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("showNotification", expirationHandler: nil)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification) {
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Notification Got", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

My Notifier object that builds and schedules notifications

```
func scheduleNotifications(reminder: ReminderMO) {
    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertTitle = reminder.name
    notification.alertBody = reminder.name
    notification.alertAction = "open"
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    notification.repeatInterval = .Day
    notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
    notification.fireDate = reminder.timeRange?.startDate
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

`reminder.timeRange?.startDate` is an `NSDate` object that when I inspect it appears to be what I expect. It comes from a `UIDatePicker`.

Problem is, when I breakpoint on the `didReceiveLocalNotification` function, it never fires.

Comment: When do you firing `scheduleNotifications` method?

Comment: Your code works correctly, The problem may be in `notification.fireDate = reminder.timeRange?.startDate` OR in the way you call `scheduleNotifications ` OR just because notification fires and couldn't launch `Alert` so try to put `print` statement into `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate.

Comment: Have you ensured that `timeRange` is not `nil` and that the app has permission to send notifications (maybe you have turned it off in the Settings app during testing)?